# How to replace a word through a variable after searching?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed, bin

I have a problem like this. In a text file(which is called sampleText.txt) has the web url like this,

```
webURL = "localhost.com";
```

I want to change this value using a bash script. But I 
tried with this my script, bt it did not worked, 
here is my script,

---

```
#!/bin/bash 

URL=$(awk -F\" '/^webURL/{print $2}' sampleText.txt)

echo $URL 


if [ "$URL" != "www.google.com" ]; then

shopt -s globstar for file in sampleText.txt 

do

   sed -i.bak 's/$URL/www.google.com/g' $file 

done 

fi
```

---

I hope you will help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thankx... :)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: What purpose does `shopt -s globstar` serve here?

Comment: @fedorqui , after running this script nothing will be changed to the webURL part of the file (sampleText.txt), it remains same as before. Currently the webURL=hht://localhost.com , I need to change this as webURL= www.google.lk . Thank You, Hope you will reply me, Any help would be greatly appreciated...... :)

Comment: @user3440631 Also have you checked the output of `awk -F\" '/^webURL/{print $2}' sampleText.txt` line? is it display url?

Comment: @Jayesh, yes it is displayed the webURL value clearly...that part is working fine, bt the replace this is not working,,,...

Comment: @user3440631 ok..and as devnull said` `What purpose does shopt -s globstar serve here?` Also try my solution as below answer instead your for `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intent, you want to change every URL in lines which begin with `webURL =` to "www.google.com"? If so, you simply

```
$ sed -i.bak -r '/^webURL/{s/"[^"]+"/"www.google.com"/}' sampleText.txt
```

If you have a mixture of single and double quotes, you can use

```
$ sed -i.bak -r "/^webURL/{s/['\"][^'\"]+[\"']/\"www.google.com\"/}"
```

which will normalise to double quotes.

Comment: if the webURL with single quote (webURL = 'http://sampledoamin.com') , so how the below line would be changed to string searching start with single quote,? 

** {$ sed -i.bak -r '/^webURL/{s/"[^"]+"/"www.google.com"/}' sampleText.txt }**

hope you will help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: @user3440631 just change to single quotes. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "s|\("webURL" *= *\).*|\1www.google.com|" sampleText.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

the script can be update to:

```
#!/bin/bash 

url="www.google.com"
sed -i.bak "/^webURL/{s@\"[^\"]*\"@\"$url\"@}" sampleText.txt
```